# Using Java to connect to an Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

This Java code compiles fine, but when I try to run it I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //connect to database
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        String serverName = "000.000.000.000";
        String portNumber = "1521";
        String sid = "abcd";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
}
```

How do I get this to work? I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and JDK 6.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to download the Oracle JDBC driver and put it on your classpath.

Comment: do you have appropriate jar file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the Oracle jars.

You can get them from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html).

Comment: You'll probably want to grab ojdbc6.jar from that link.

Comment: It says:
ojdbc6.jar (2,714,189 bytes) - Classes for use with JDK 1.6.

But I have JDK 6??

Comment: Ah I see, they are the same: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/version-6-141920.html

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is it still present in mvn repo ?

Comment: It's not public right now. I had to register previously in the Oracle Maven Repository. 

More info here: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010)

Answer (score 3):

Add *ojdbcXX.jar*-where XX is version number-to Java build path of your project. Aside from the classpath issue, requesting "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" is deprecated. For a long time it has been recommended to use: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver". For some more recent driver versions, the former will not even work.

Comment: Why that jar? And where can I get it?

Comment: Oh no sorry you would use ojdbc6.jar as this is for java 6. (1.6 is the same as 6 naming conventions for java changed). The one i referenced was for java 1.4!

Answer (score 1):

Also, you have to add those jars to your project. @Netbeans, you can easily do that at the project-properties